# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined`, but I can't for my life figure out what is wrong!

```
var anchor = [];
getAnchors();
function getAnchors() {
    $('.anchor').each(function(i) {
        anchor[i] = $(this).offset().left;
    });
}
```

So what is wrong with this code snippet?
I have declared `anchor` as an array.
I've been checking for silly typos for an hour now.
The error lies in `i`. But what *is* the error?

**Edit:**
[I found out what's wrong.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17207345/1508933)

Comment: 1st problem I notice is that you're assigning non indexed keys to the array. Did you mean `anchor[i] = {}`?

Comment: An array doesn't have keys like that, you're looking for an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.map` to build arrays :

```
var anchor;
function getAnchors() {
    anchor = $.map($('.anchor'), function(el) { return $(el).offset().left; });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try returning the array instead? Like this:

```
function getAnchors() {
    var allAnchors = [];
    $('.anchor').each(function(i) {
        allAnchors.push($(this).offset().left);
    });
    return allAnchors;
}

var anchor = getAnchors();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the object property before you assign a value to it.

```
    var anchor = [];
    $('.anchor').each(function(i) {
        anchor[i] = [{
            pos: null,
            id: null
        }];
        anchor[i]['pos'] = $(this).offset().left;
        anchor[i]['id'] = $(this).attr('id');
    });
```

then make the assignment and overwrite null with your values.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I just had to declare `anchor` in the function instead.

```
getAnchors();
function getAnchors() {
    var anchor = [];
    $('.anchor').each(function(i) {
        anchor[i] = $(this).offset().left;
    });
    // perhaps sort anchor
    console.log(anchor);
}
```

Thanks for the replies though.

Comment: There's no point on doing that TBH. Check @adaneo's answer if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var anchors = $('.anchor').map(function() {
  return {
    pos: $(this).offset().left,
    id: this.id
  }
}).get();
```